# Log4j2 ConsoleAppender not applying PatternLayout

Tags: java

I am running Tomcat 8.0.9 and using log4j2.  I have a pattern layout defined on the console appender which is set to SYSTEM_OUT.  The layout pattern is something like:

%d{yyyy-MM-dd} %m%n

but when a System.out.println is invoked the pattern is not applied.  Should I be expecting that the pattern will be applied to System.out.println?

Answer (score 2):

> Should I be expecting that the pattern will be applied to System.out.println?

No.

Pattern (and the whole log4j configuration) applies only to the log4j components (i.e. loggers, appenders, layouts, etc). `SYSTEM_OUT` target means that ConsoleAppender will use `System.out` to print *pre-formatted* log messages to console.

So to get formatted log output you must use log4j logger:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class LoggingTest {
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("This text will be formatted");
        System.out.println("This won't");
    }
}
```

Of course configuration file must be in the classpath or "log4j.configurationFile" system propery specified.

Comment: Thanks Alex.  That makes sense but I was not sure.  I do have a follow on.  The Tomcat start up INFO messages also are not using any of my patterns for the console appender or the file appender I have set up.  My guess is that they are not using log4j2 implementation since the Tomcat default is juli???

Comment: @Michelle, there are libraries that "unify" various other logging frameworks. All logging is then redirected to a common back-end, such as log4j2. One example is [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org).

Comment: @jackrabbit That's true, but not so simple to apply to Tomcat (I mean logging of the container itself, not web applications). From [their documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/logging.html): "The internal logging for Apache Tomcat uses JULI, a packaged renamed fork of Apache Commons Logging that, by default, is hard-coded to use the java.util.logging framework." So to "redirect" logging you must provide binding to their custom logging API.

Comment: @Michelle Why do you want to use log4j2 for Tomcat? You could configure it's built-in logging (configuration format is the same as java.util.logging). It's independent from web apps logging.

Comment: @AlexFilatov SLF4J also allows redirecting JUL, albeit through an appender. Since that is the eventual target of this JULI (which I had not heard of before), you can still redirect it.

Answer (score -2):

Please try with :
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

it worked for me.